# Is there a numpy function similar to np.isin that allows for a tolerance instead of requiring that values be identical?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting, numpy-slicing

I have two arrays of different sizes and want to determine where elements of one array can be found in the other array.  I would like to be able to allow for a tolerance between elements.  The goal would be something like this:

```
array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
array2 = [2, 8, 1.00001, 1.1]

places = [mystery function](array1, array2, tolerance = 0.001)
```

returning indices `places = [0,1]` in `array1`.

The closest I can get is with `np.isin`, which allows for arrays of different sizes and orders, but not the tolerance.  (have also tried `np.allclose` but the shape and order mismatch is an issue there).  Of course this can be done with a loop, but my actual arrays are thousands of elements long so a loop is not practical.

(it also doesn't have to be a numpy function--really just anything more efficient than a loop)

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: So this shape and dimension mismatch scares you so much you can't even detail it?  You won't be able to avoid numpy loops with that hangup.  `isin` avoids this because it reduces the task to a 1d one that can then use sorting.

Comment: Use searchsorted then compare the diff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With custom function to find the absolute difference between 2 arrays and positions which fit the given tolerance:

```
array1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
array2 = np.array([2, 8, 1.00001, 1.1])
tolerance = 0.001

def argwhere_close(a, b, tol):
    return np.where(np.any(np.abs(a - b[:, None]) <= tolerance, axis=0))[0]

print(argwhere_close(array1, array2, tolerance))
```

---

```
[0 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

While I don't specifically know of a function in numpy, I did just write one.

Hope this helps:

```
import numpy as np

def find_indices_within_tolerance(array1, array2, tolerance):
    results = []
    for i, a1_elem in enumerate(array1):
        for a2_elem in array2:
            if abs(a1_elem - a2_elem) <= tolerance:
                results.append(i)
    results = list(set(results))
    results.sort()
    return results

array1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
array2 = np.array([2, 8, 1.00001, 1.1])

places = find_indices_within_tolerance(array1, array2, tolerance=0.001)

print(places)

-> yields: [0, 1]
```

Comment: Hi!  Thank you so much for the answer!  This is super helpful, but is it possible to do this without sorting array1--in my data, sorted array1 is different from unsorted, and it's important I get the "places" indices for the unsorted array

Comment: @celery please check and see if this does what you need now. The process is a bit slower, as it's functionally matrix multiplication to compare elements.